# changing text size in @media function (css)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, media-queries

I have this code in html:

```
  <section class="aboutUs">
   <h1>title</h1>
   <h2>texttextetxtetxtetxtetxtetxtetxt<br>lorem ipsum text text text</h2>
 </section>
```

and this in css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {

.aboutUs h1 {
    font-size: 5vw;       
}
.aboutUs h2 {
    font-size: 5vw;
}
```

I want to make the h1 and h2 texts bigger but it seems like it's not working not sure why

Comment: Are your `h1` and `h2` elements actually children of an element with the class `.aboutUs`?

Comment: hi. 
this looks fine. can you provide more code. Initial classes of that elements and about us class

Comment: The code you posted is okay. If it doesn't affect anything, there might be a more specific (i.e. more complex selectors) font-size setting in the CSS for the regular styles. Also be careful to post those media queries *after*  the regular css rules.

Answer (score 0):

fixed there was

```
#default .aboutUs h1 {
font-size: 2.5vw;
letter-spacing: .1vw;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 2vw 1vw 1vw;
}
```

in the css but as the code wasn't mine I didn't notice it

I removed font-size: 2.5;